# Why is this autogen.sh script failing?

Tags: compiling, make, window-manager, automake

I've downloaded [this](https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin) window manager from github and it has a `autogen.sh` script but it failed each time.

I don't know what could happen or how to fix it:

Output from `./autogen.sh`:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh
checking for autoreconf >= 2.53...
  testing autoreconf... found 2.69
checking for glib-gettext >= 2.2.0...
  testing glib-gettextize... found 2.40.0
checking for intltool >= 0.25...
  testing intltoolize... found 0.50.2
checking for pkg-config >= 0.14.0...
  testing pkg-config... found 0.26
checking for gnome-doc-utils >= 0.4.2...
  testing gnome-doc-prepare... found 0.20.10
checking for gnome-common >= 2.3.0...
  testing gnome-doc-common... found 3.10.0
Checking for required M4 macros...
Checking for forbidden M4 macros...
**Warning**: I am going to run `configure' with no arguments.
If you wish to pass any to it, please specify them on the
`./autogen.sh' command line.

Processing ./configure.ac
Running glib-gettextize... Ignore non-fatal messages.
Copying file po/Makefile.in.in

Please add the files
  codeset.m4 gettext.m4 glibc21.m4 iconv.m4 isc-posix.m4 lcmessage.m4
  progtest.m4
from the /usr/share/aclocal directory to your autoconf macro directory
or directly to your aclocal.m4 file.
You will also need config.guess and config.sub, which you can get from
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/config/.

Running gnome-doc-common...
Running gnome-doc-prepare...
You should update your 'aclocal.m4' by running aclocal.
Running intltoolize...
Running autoreconf...
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force --warnings=no-portability 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.ac and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force --warnings=no-portability
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing --warnings=no-portability
src/Makefile.am:205: error: HAVE_INTROSPECTION does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
src/Makefile.am:8: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/async-getprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However,
automake: this behaviour will change in future Automake versions: they will
automake: unconditionally cause object files to be placed in the same subdirectory
automake: of the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/bell.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/boxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/cogl-utils.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/compositor.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-background-actor.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-module.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-plugin.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-plugin-manager.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-shadow-factory.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-shaped-texture.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-texture-rectangle.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-texture-tower.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-window-actor.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-window-group.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/meta-window-shape.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'compositor/region-utils.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/above-tab-keycode.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/constraints.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/core.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/delete.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/display.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/draw-workspace.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/edge-resistance.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/errors.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/eventqueue.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/frame.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/theme.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/ui.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/preview-widget.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:202: warning: source file 'core/muffin.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:202: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:197: warning: source file 'ui/theme-viewer.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:197: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/testasyncgetprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/async-getprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/testboxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/boxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/util.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:245: warning: source file 'ui/testgradient.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:245: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/compositor/plugins/Makefile.am:4: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/tools/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/wm-tester/Makefile.am:2: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1:33: warning: source file 'ui/theme.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/ui.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/preview-widget.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:202: warning: source file 'core/muffin.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:202: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:197: warning: source file 'ui/theme-viewer.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:197: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/testasyncgetprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/async-getprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/testboxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/boxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/util.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:245: warning: source file 'ui/testgradient.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:245: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/compositor/plugins/Makefile.am:4: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/tools/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/wm-tester/Makefile.am:2: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/gradient.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/group-props.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/group.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/iconcache.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/keybindings.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/main.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/place.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/theme.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/ui.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/preview-widget.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:202: warning: source file 'core/muffin.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:202: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:197: warning: source file 'ui/theme-viewer.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:197: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/testasyncgetprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/async-getprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/testboxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/boxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/util.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:245: warning: source file 'ui/testgradient.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:245: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/compositor/plugins/Makefile.am:4: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/tools/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/wm-tester/Makefile.am:2: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1:33: warning: source file 'core/prefs.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/screen.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/session.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/stack.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/stack-tracker.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/util.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/window-props.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/window.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/workspace.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'core/xprops.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/frames.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/tile-hud.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/menu.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/metaaccellabel.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/resizepopup.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/tabpopup.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/tile-preview.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/theme-parser.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/theme.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/ui.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:33: warning: source file 'ui/preview-widget.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:33: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:202: warning: source file 'core/muffin.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:202: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:197: warning: source file 'ui/theme-viewer.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:197: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/testasyncgetprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:246: warning: source file 'core/async-getprop.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:246: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/testboxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/boxes.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:244: warning: source file 'core/util.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:244: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/Makefile.am:245: warning: source file 'ui/testgradient.c' is in a subdirectory,
src/Makefile.am:245: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
src/compositor/plugins/Makefile.am:4: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/tools/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
src/wm-tester/Makefile.am:2: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

or:
http://pastebin.com/dJx2hkEz

Comment: Also, not sure what tags should be here.

Comment: Can you please tell me which package and what error you are getting while executing the autogen script? I'm not able to access that website(link) because of some network restrictions.Or you can try running the `configure` script if you have.

Comment: and you can specify `--prefix=/some/install/dir` option to indicate where installation should happen.

Comment: You say you downloaded the code from github, could you provide a link to the repository?

Comment: @Codingale: Can you paste the output of `autogen` in the question itself instead of giving a link?.

Comment: I suggest pasting the output in the question itself. What if the link is not valid tomorrow?.No one can refer to this question.

Comment: Can you try taking some other lower stable version and build it? I was trying to install but I need to install lot of dependency packages.Get the source from this link `https://github.com/linuxmint/muffin/tags` and try `autogen.sh`.Can you give me your linux distribution details?

Comment: Linux Mint, 17, I have all the packages required I think.  and doing apt-get install muffin gets a old version. I'll try that when I wake up. Sorry been up trying to recover my old files since I posted this.

Comment: Okay, somehow I tried it again today after downloading a new version and it built just fine... I'm not sure what the issue is/was maybe a error in the script I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

The missing macros are in package `gettext-tools`.

Comment: On what Unix? With what package manager?

Comment: I've got them on open suse (yast) and debian (synaptic) or go direct to https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gettext/

Comment: @robert - Your answer should indicate that is the case.  You should be specific on all the actions you took to resolve the problem.  [I am providing feedback since you seem to want to know how to improve this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343311/can-you-fact-check-an-answer-or-comment-or-vote-on-stack-exchange-like-i-spen)